# In ADO.NET, how do specify that a column in a DataTable is required?

Tags: .net, ado.net

In ADO.NET, how do specify that a column in a DataTable is required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following would do the trick. Just fill in the correct table and column name.

```
DataSet1.Tables("Table1").Columns("Column1").AllowDBNull = False
```